# Why some sync functions are executed in a unusual order

Tags: node.js, asynchronous, synchronization

In this application, I want to maintain a log file. some exceptions can be thrown while it's executed. If there is an exception, i want to log that too. But what actually happening is application is terminated before the message is logged into log file. I tried using promise only for the `log()` method, which doesn't fixed the order. How can i fix this issue? If i'm using promises, do i have to use promises withing every methods (or return new promise in every method)? or are there any other better solution? Is `createWriteStream.write()` a `asynchronous` function? If it is why does't it have a call back?

```
//this is my object
var fileHandler = function () {};

//this log everything into a log file
fileHandler.prototype.log = function (logContent) {
    var logWriter = FS.createWriteStream(logFilePath, {
        flags: 'w',
        defaultEncoding: 'utf8',
        autoClose: true
    });
    console.log(logContent);
    logWriter.write(logContent+'\n');

/*
promise.resolve()
.then(function () {
   var logWriter = FS.createWriteStream(logFilePath, {
            flags: 'w',
            defaultEncoding: 'utf8',
            autoClose: true
        });
   console.log(logContent);
})
.then(function () {
   logWriter.write(logContent+'\n');
})
*/


};


//Expedted result:
//if "isTrue" == false, 
//01.this.log() should write the message to file
//02.after that print "test" in console
//03.and then terminate the application with an exception

//But the actual result:
//when i debug        
//logWriter.write(logContent+'\n'); is executed 
//but doesn't log the message before an exceptions is thrown.
fileHandler.prototype.createItem = function (isTrue) {

  if(isTrue){
    this.log('it\'s true');
  }
  else{
    this.log('newException : it\'s not true');
    throw new this.setUserException('newException', 'it\'s not true');
  }
};


//create new instance
var projectModule = new fileHandler();

//add cteate method to projectModule object
projectModule.create = function (isTrue) {
  this.createItem(isTrue);
};

//call create function
projectModule.create(false);
```

Comment: Yes `write` function is asynchronous function.See here : (https://nodejs.org/api/stream.html#stream_writable_write_chunk_encoding_callback) .If you are using promises then resolve/reject your promise in callback of `write` function.

Comment: Here main problem is when writing operation is going on, throw statement will be executed(because write op is async) so before logging msg to log file program will be terminated.

Comment: @Sarju I have already added promise resolve. but the thing is promise chain is executed after all sync functions are executed within the application. so, cover  that method with a promise isn't my solution

Comment: you are doing something wrong.See here I have created code snippet , http://pastie.org/10848362 look at this.Here I have used `q` library for promise.